# Ho to select only the row with date+time-stamp as a column value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called call_history with one column incoming_call.
It has a datatype of datetime.
however currently some value has only dates like : 6/1/2014 and some has datetime values like: 6/1/2014 12:01:56 AM.

How do i select the rows with datetime values leaving behind rows with only dates?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the TRUNC function which will only give nearest date to achieve the same.For example trunc without date format of 12-Aug-2014 23:59:59 will return 12-Aug-2014 and trunc of 13-Aug-2014 00:00:01 will return 13-Aug-2014.Similarly Trunc of 12-Aug-2014 will give 12-Aug-2014.

```
 SELECT * FROM     CALL_HISTORY WHERE TRUNC(DATETIME) <> DATETIME;
```